# Get only folder name from url in php without any file name with extension

Tags: php, html, url

I want to get foldername without any file name from a url in php?

My url is http://w3schools.com/php/demo/learningphp.php?lid=1348

I only want to retrieve the  http://w3schools.com/php/demo from the url?

How to do this? Please help.

Comment: Using [parse_url](http://php.net/parse-url) and an `explode` on the `path` component, it should be very easy

Comment: sub folder name is dynamic

Comment: Have a look at `parse_url` and input whatever your input is

Comment: Consider that, most of the cases, what you get is not the folder path but just a URL (I tell you just because you got a third-party URL as example)

Comment: Did you like either of the answers here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$URL = 'http://w3schools.com/php/demo/learningphp.php?lid=1348';
$URL_SEGMENTS = explode("/", $URL);

foreach($URL_SEGMENTS as $Segment){
  echo $Segment;
}
```

`explode()` will separate the string with `/` and provide an `array`. So you will have all url segments in foreach loop and you use it or store it in `string` or `array`.

After your comment let me show the script which will return your desire url.

```
$Desired_URL = $URL_SEGMENTS[2].'/'.$URL_SEGMENTS[3].'/'.$URL_SEGMENTS[4];
echo $Desired_URL;
```

Comment: Sir its explode the /  but i need http://w3schools.com/php/demo/
this kind of output

Comment: What is "this kind of output"?

Answer (score 0):

If the url is stored in $url:

```
$url = 'http://w3schools.com/php/demo/learningphp.php?lid=1348';
```

You can do a preg_replace like so:

```
print(preg_replace('/\/[^\/]*$/', '', $url));
http://w3schools.com/php/demo
```

That regex means to replace everything from a / and all characters that are not / ... [^/]* ... to the end of the string ... $ ... with an empty string. Just delete them.